# How to set up webcam for skype conversation?

Tags: 14.04, sound, skype

I have bought Goldentec webcam.When I go to Volume Control,Input Devices I see 
Builtin Digital Stereo(IEC958).Is my webcam not being recognized?How to change this?

milenko@milenko-X58-USB3:~$ ls -la /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Fev  1 11:07 /dev/video0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that your Webcam is correctly running by using something like VLC. And that it has been correctly recognized by using dmesg (and looking at the last lines after plugging it in).

EDIT: To do so while using VLC: Open the playlist (CTRL+L) and go to "Video Capture" then a device should be there if it's not it hasn't been found.

EDIT2: Did you check that /dev/video* exists?
Command:

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Comment: /dev/video0
Yes,it exists.

Comment: Ok, that means your webcam (or another video device, like TV card) has successfully been found and a fitting drivers is being used for it. Normally this would mean it's also available for other programs. 
If I understand it correct Skype does not list it? Do the test with VLC. If you can't access it with VLC, check permissions (just add "-la" after ls)

EDIT: It could be your user is not added to the video group.
If that's the case do so using usermod -a -G video "yourname"
and relog.

Comment: Or use cheese (sudp apt-get install cheese)

Comment: You can check groups by using the command:"groups" (without root)

Comment: @konard I have tryed with cheese,video is workig but how to solve the sound?

Comment: @The19thFighter I got milenko adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Comment: Ah, you want to use your Webcams microphone? You should specify that on your question.
Use "aplay -L" to get all found sound cards. Maybe post the output